# AVG in HiveQL - Error when I try to get the average of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to get the total average of temperature(one column on my DB from table w) of each `StationID` (one column on my DB from table s).

My query:

```
SELECT s.zipcode AS Zipcode, AVG(w.precip) AS Preciptation FROM stationData s JOIN weatherReport w ON s.stationid = w.stationid;
```

Error:

> Your query has the following error(s):
>   OK FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'zipcode'
>   ok failed: semanticexception [error 10025]: line 1:7 expression not in group by key 'zipcode'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group your query if you use `AVG()`.

Try with:

```
SELECT s.zipcode AS Zipcode, AVG(w.precip) AS Preciptation FROM stationData s JOIN weatherReport w ON s.stationid = w.stationid group by s.zipcode;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried this query, it gives the same message error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause on Zipcode since you are using an aggregate function on Precipitation

```
SELECT s.zipcode AS Zipcode, AVG(w.precip) AS Preciptation 
FROM stationData s 
JOIN weatherReport w ON s.stationid = w.stationid
GROUP BY s.zipcode
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried this query, it gives the same error as before.